# With Google script, Insert 4:3 image into Google Slide of 16:9 ratio, then export it as PNG file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-slides-api, google-slides

With Google Apps script I'm trying to automate the process of inserting 4:3 image file (in Google Drive) into an empty slide of 16:9 ratio, aligning the image to the centre, then export the slide as PNG file.

I encountered the issue that the exported PNG file is still an empty slide and missing the inserted image.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Slides API enabled.

Please see below the code I have written so far:

```
const file = DriveApp.openById(#####);
const presentation1 = SlidesApp.openById(######);

var slide = presentation1.getSlides()[0];
var image = slide.insertImage(file);
image.alignOnPage(SlidesApp.AlignmentPosition.HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
        

var url = Slides.Presentations.Pages.getThumbnail(pptImageConverterId, slide.getObjectId(), {
          "thumbnailProperties.mimeType": "PNG"
        }).contentUrl;
var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getAs('image/png');
folder.createFile(blob.setName("Slide1.png"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to remove your issue of `I encountered the issue that the exported PNG file is still an empty slide and missing the inserted image.`. This is your question.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `pptImageConverterId` and `folder` are not declared. `pptImageConverterId` is the same with `######` of `SlidesApp.openById(######);`?
- `DriveApp.openById(#####);` is not correct. Is that `DriveApp.getFileById("###");`?
- About `aligning the image to the centre`, in this case, I thought that you might have wanted `SlidesApp.AlignmentPosition.CENTER` instead of `SlidesApp.AlignmentPosition.HORIZONTAL_CENTER`.

But, you say `I encountered the issue that the exported PNG file is still an empty slide and missing the inserted image.`. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your script.

When I saw your script, if the above points are modified, I thought that the reason for your issue is due to that `saveAndClose()` is not used. When these are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please set `pptImageConverterId`, `fileId`, and `folderId`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const pptImageConverterId = "###"; // Please set your Google Slides ID.
  const fileId = "###"; // Please set the file ID of the image you want to use.
  const folderId = "###"; // Please set the folder ID you want to use.
  
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  const presentation1 = SlidesApp.openById(pptImageConverterId);
  var slide = presentation1.getSlides()[0];
  var image = slide.insertImage(file);
  image.alignOnPage(SlidesApp.AlignmentPosition.CENTER);
  presentation1.saveAndClose();
  var url = Slides.Presentations.Pages.getThumbnail(pptImageConverterId, slide.getObjectId(), {
    "thumbnailProperties.mimeType": "PNG"
  }).contentUrl;
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
  DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile(blob.setName("Slide1.png"));
}
```

- When this script is run, an image is put to the 1st slide of the Google Slides, and the slide is exported as a PNG file.

#### References:

- [getFileById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid)
- [saveAndClose()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#saveandclose)

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! saveAndClose() is essential what I need!

And yes I did miscopy my script so the code is a bit all over the place. 

I got another question: how I do set the size of the exported PNG file to 1920x1080? By default it gives me 1600x900.

Comment: @half.dead Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `I got another question: how I do set the size of the exported PNG file to 1920x1080? By default it gives me 1600x900.`, when you use `thumbnailProperties.thumbnailSize: "LARGE"`, what result will you obtain? But, the document says `LARGE: The thumbnail image width of 1600px.`. So if that was not your expected result, I apologize.

Comment: oh no need to apologise at all. I didn't even mention anything about thumbnail size in the first place and the question just kind of pops up. You have been tremendously helpful mate. 

Yup tested with thumbnailProperties.thumbnailSize: "LARGE" and it's 1600x900. There's nothing mentioned in the documentation that I can go higher than 1600px so maybe it's the max resolution I could go for?

Comment: @half.dead Thank you for replying. In this case, it seems that the width of 1600 pixels is the maximum size.

Comment: No worries I will settle with 1600px then. Thanks for your help once again!